# При использовании selenium сайт думает, что используется впн, и ограничивает доступ. Как попасть на сайт?

Tags: python, парсер, selenium, selenium-webdriver, vpn

хотел получать некоторые данные с сайта Leroy Merlin, а именно конкретную информацию о товаре по прямой ссылке. Решил делать через Selenium, потому что нужно выполнять JS код. Написал такой код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
import random

user_agents = [
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 '
'Safari/537.36',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
]

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(f'--user-agent={random.choice(user_agents)}')
link = 'https://leroymerlin.ru/product/el-novogodnyaya-iskusstvennaya-krasivaya-240-sm- 
14652317/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(link)
time.sleep(5)
```

сайт открывается, но вылезает вот такое окно(впн у меня выключен):
[image: впн у меня выключен]

подскажите пожалуйста, что можно сделать в этом случае?